# Overriding plugin views in Grails 2.2

Tags: grails, plugins, view, gsp, taglib

I'm trying to customize the HTML markup of the excellent FilterPane grails plugin, however I'm having some difficulty. FilterPane provides a bunch of tags for rendering the search/filter form, and I would like to override these in my application.

I had thought that I could simply copy the `_tagName.gsp`s that I wanted to override from

`plugins/filterpane-2.0.1.1/grails-app/views/filterpane`

into

`grails-app/views/filterpane`

and modify them, however it looks like Grails never checks whether the application is overriding the views of a plugin, if the render method is called with a plugin name property specified.

`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.findAndCacheTemplate` contains the following code in a private method:

```
...
GroovyPageScriptSource scriptSource;
if (pluginName == null) {
    scriptSource = groovyPageLocator.findTemplateInBinding(templatePath, pageScope);
}  else {
    scriptSource = groovyPageLocator.findTemplateInBinding(pluginName, templatePath, pageScope);
}
...
```

so when a non-null `pluginName` is specified, we just grab the plugin's view and never check whether the application is overriding it.

I thought a simple way to get around this problem would be to just override `GrailsConventionGroovyPageLocator.findTemplateInBinding`, or some other similar method in `GrailsConventionGroovyPageLocator`, however it doesn't appear to be possible to do this from within a Grails application either!

I created a simple class overriding `GrailsConventionGroovyPageLocator`, replacing the `findTemplateInBinding` method with one that checks the application's view directory before checking that of the plugin. I then modified `resources.groovy`, adding a doWithSpring closure to replace the `beanClass` property of the default `groovyPageLocator`:

```
def doWithSpring = {
    def pageLocator = delegate.getBeanDefinition("groovyPageLocator")
    pageLocator.beanClass = MyConventionGroovyPageLocator
}
```

However this doesn't seem to be called when my application starts up.

I'm really at a loss here. I'd expected this to be straightforward, but it's turned into a bit of a can of worms. Does anyone have any suggestions? All I want to do is override the views provided by a plugin...

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the plugin source, instead of changing the location of the template.

The location is: `user_home\.grails\version\projects\project\plugins\plugin-name`

Comment: Yes I could, and it may come to that, but I'm really hoping that I can find a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a grails expert, but in order to override plugin views you should recreate them in your main projects views folder. For example, I changed the `/auth/login.gsp` from Spring Security Plugin by simply creating the same thing in my `/project/views/auth/login.gsp`. If you make changes into the plugin files itself you could potentially lose them if you uninstall the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change a view in a template of a plugin, perform the command

`grails install-templates`

[source](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html)

This will copy the templates of the plugins to your project which you then can customize. What this does with for example the scaffolding plugin, is copy files to src/templates/scaffolding (note, not *grails-app*/templates/scaffolding). Therefore, in your case, I would try copying the files to src/views/filterpane

Comment: This does not work, because of the reasons described by @rcgeorge23. Grails does not check your app's templates, when running from a plugin. In other words, the plugin gets its templates only from itself.